# Why does a function call in Rust not compile when a manually inlined version works?

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust MCVE:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct X {
    x: i32,
}
                 
fn fold1<I: Iterator, F>(mut it: I, f: F) -> I::Item
where
    I::Item: Clone,
    F: FnMut(I::Item, I::Item) -> I::Item, 
{
    let init = it.next().unwrap().clone();
    it.fold(init, f)
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![X { x: 1 }, X { x: 2 }];

    // This does not compile:
    let s = fold1(v.iter(), |a, b| X { x: a.x + b.x }); 

    println!("{}", s.x);
}
```

This doesn't compile with the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> example.rs:19:36
   |
19 |     let s = fold1(v.iter(), |a, b| X { x: a.x + b.x });
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&X`, found `X`
   |
help: consider borrowing here
   |
19 |     let s = fold1(v.iter(), |a, b| &X { x: a.x + b.x });
   |                                    +

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

However, if I instead manually inline the function:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct X {
    x: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![X { x: 1 }, X { x: 2 }];

    // The inlined version, however, does:
    let mut it = v.iter();
    let init = it.next().unwrap().clone();
    let s = it.fold(init, |a, b| X { x: a.x + b.x });

    println!("{}", s.x);
}
```

then everything is fine. The code compiles and does what was intended.

I really can't see any difference here. What am I doing wrong?

(And, as a followup, is it possible to write a function like `fold1` that would clone the first element of the iterator and then use it as the initial element for `fold`? No, `reduce` is not the answer. Calling `cloned()` on the iterator is not the answer either. I really want to only clone *the first one*, not all of them.)

Comment: Full error message added per request; not that it is too helpful. (Adding `&` doesn't work, of course, because that would be a reference to a temporary.)

Comment: `.clone()` is `X::clone` in the second example, but [`<&X>::clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#trait-implementations-1) in the first

Comment: FYI: The full error message might not help you or me all that much but it helps when a future visitor is searching for their problem. Since building a knowledge base is SOs target searchability is always a plus!

Comment: Working solution: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=061e1439b7016b03a90dc88bf95ad3a4)

Comment: @Jmb So this is how I unwrap the reference I get from the iterator! I understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your working code, you are calling `fold::<X, FnMut (X, &X) -> X>` but in the non-working case, you try to call `fold::<&X, FnMut (&X, &X) -> &X>`, since `I::Item` is `&X`. This can't work because the return type of your closure is not the same as the initial `fold` value. You need to change the declaration of `fold1` so that it will match the working code:

```
fn fold1<'a, T, I: Iterator<Item = &'a T>, F> (mut it: I, f: F) -> T
where
    T: Clone + 'a,
    F: FnMut (T, &'a T) -> T, 
{
    let init = it.next().unwrap().clone();
    it.fold (init, f)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=061e1439b7016b03a90dc88bf95ad3a4)